# AS3 How to dispatch timer event to another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, dispatch

I am trying to dispatch event every second from Mytimer class and catch the event from Main class. I've declared variable "sus" as integer = 10. I have nothing so far, no output, nothing. Some help please!

This is Mytimer.as

```
    private function onUpdateTime(event:Event):void
    {

        nCount--;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("tickTack", true));
        //Stop timer when it reaches 0
        if (nCount == 0)
        {
            _timer.reset();
            _timer.stop();
            _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onUpdateTime);
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

And in Main.as I have:

```
    public function Main()
    {
        // constructor code
        _timer = new MyTimer  ;
        stage.addEventListener("tickTack", ontickTack);
    }

    function ontickTack(e:Event)
    {
        sus--;
        trace(sus);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Main.as`, you have added the listener to the stage, not your timer. This line:

```
stage.addEventListener("tickTack", ontickTack);
```

should be like this:

```
_timer.addEventListener("tickTack", ontickTack);
```

---

But ActionScript already has a `Timer` class that looks like it has all the functionality you need. No need to reinvent the wheel. Take a look at the [documentation for the Timer class](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html).

In your main you could just say:

```
var count:int = 10; // the number of times the timer will repeat.
_timer = new Timer(1000, count); // Creates timer of one second, with repeat.
_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimerTimer);
_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, handleTimerTimerComplete);
```

Then just add your handler methods. You don't need to use both. Often the TIMER event is enough. Something like this:

```
private function handleTimerTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // Fires each time the timer reaches the interval.
}

private function handleTimerTimer(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // Fired when all repeat have finished.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thanks. This is what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick answer. I am doing this because I want to keep my timer in separate class, so I can access its timing any time. I found this way as a very convenient. Thanks Adam

Comment: No worries @irnik, remember to mark the answer as correct if you found what you want.